# Get Float part in Int

Tags: java, android, double

I am developing an app in which i have to get the float part in terms of integer value.

for example if my number is `153.12324` then output should be `12324`.I tried this way but it works wrong some time.

What's the problem in this or is there a better way to do this ?

there is a double value in d

```
    double d =any_double_value;
    String[] splitter = String.valueOf(d).split("\\.");
    splitter[0].length();   // Before Decimal Count
    int count = splitter[1].length();
    int integerpart = (int) calcResult;
    double floatpart = calcResult - integerpart;
    while (count!=0)
    {
        floatpart=floatpart*10;
        count--;
    }

    int floatpartinInt=(int)floatpart;
```

this works wrong only in some cases(it gives 1 number less, like if answer is 124 it gives 123) and in cases where answer is long double no like   3.333333333  (10/3)

Comment: Do you mean 'get the *fractional* part'?

Comment: A wonderful mistake: 1.00023 and 1.000229 will give 23 and 229. Floating point is a rough approximation and has no precise number of digits as string.

Answer (score 3):

You can also without `split`. by using following way,

```
double value = 3.25;
double fractionalPart = value % 1;
double integralPart = value - fractionalPart;
```

This may helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use this code its work in your case and enjoy Man

```
double val=1.9;
    String[] arr=String.valueOf(val).split("\\.");
    int[] intArr=new int[2];
    intArr[0]=Integer.parseInt(arr[0]); // 1
    intArr[1]=Integer.parseInt(arr[1]); // 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
lvalue = (long) value;
fPart = value - lvalue;
```